# Will JVM optimise this mathmatical operation?

Tags: java, jvm, runtime

`long time= (getTime()/60000L) * 60000L`

The `getTime()` will return unix time in millis. I am exploiting division with longs to write off seconds and millis. The result must also be in unix time format (resolution upto millis)

I am wondering if JVM would optimise the above code to

`long time= getTime()`

But this will alter the result.

Or is there a better, cleaner way? (Can't change getTime's return type, which is also long)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As you say, changing it in that way would modify the result. In general (there are exceptions), optimizations aren't allowed to *change* the result. I'm not an expert in JVM optimization but I'd be really shocked if it did that.

Comment: Why don't you test it?

Comment: If it did that, it would be an egregious bug.  And someone would have noticed it and fixed it.  So I would say it is implausible that this happens / would happen in any of the extant LTS Java releases ... assuming that you are using the latest patch version available.

Comment: You should of course be doing `Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);`

Comment: @g00se - Good point, or perhaps `Instant.ofEpochMilli(getTime()).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);` since we don't know what `getTime` method that is or what time it represents.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, that's also a good point [though it could *still* be wrong] ;) I was being assumptive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarizing the comments into a Community Wiki answer:

It would be a major bug if the JVM "optimized" that code in the way you describe. Intentionally using truncating division and other similar operations is common, optimizing them away would be breaking the semantics of the code. So your existing code should be just fine.

---

You asked about other ways. There are at least a couple.

You could do a remainder (`% 60000L`) and subtraction rather than division and multiplication, although that still leaves a "magic number" (`60000L`) in the code you'd need to explain with a comment or similar:

```
long time = getTime();
time = time - time % 60000L;
```

Or you could make the time semantics obvious by using the [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) class:

```
long time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(getTime())
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES)
    .toEpochMilli();
```

(You only need the `.toEpochMilli()` on the end if you need your result to be a Unix milliseconds time value again as it is in your current code; otherwise, it would be an `Instant` instance).

But again, while you *can* do either of those (and probably others), you don't have to change your code if you don't want to.